# Insert event to Google Calendar using php

Tags: php, authentication, curl, google-calendar-api, http-request

I'm trying to perform a cURL request to google calendar api using [their guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert), that says:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{name_of_my_calendar}/events?sendNotifications=true&pp=1&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  OAuth 1/SuypHO0rNsURWvMXQ559Mfm9Vbd4zWvVQ8UIR76nlJ0
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2012-06-03T10:00:00.000-07:00"
 },
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2012-06-03T10:20:00.000-07:00"
 },
 "summary": "my_summary",
 "description": "my_description"
}
```

How am I supposed to do that in php? I wonder what parameters I should send and what constants I should use. I'm currently doing:

```
        $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/".urlencode('{name_of_my_calendar}')."/events?sendNotifications=true&pp=1&key={my_api_key}";  

        $post_data = array(  
            "start" => array("dateTime" => "2012-06-01T10:00:00.000-07:00"),  
            "end" => array("dateTime" => "2012-06-01T10:40:00.000-07:00"),  
            "summary" => "my_summary",
            "description" => "my_description"
        );

        $ch = curl_init();  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
        // adding the post variables to the request  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);  

        $output = curl_exec($ch);  

        curl_close($ch);
```

but the response is:

```
{
    error: {
        errors: [
        {
            domain: "global",
            reason: "required",
            message: "Login Required",
            locationType: "header",
            location: "Authorization"
        }
        ],
        code: 401,
        message: "Login Required"
    }
}
```

How should I format my parameters?

Comment: Did you read https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth?

Comment: Yes, my code works on an example where I just parse events from the same calendar.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure, I've never worked with this API before. You may want to give the official PHP API package a try: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/ Hope this helps a bit!

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this question is asked quite some time ago, however after figuring out the post-parameter problem after some time I thought it might be useful to others to answer it. First within '$post_data', I switched the 'start' and 'end':

```
$post_data = array(
    "end" => array("dateTime" => "2012-06-01T10:40:00.000-07:00"),
    "start" => array("dateTime" => "2012-06-01T10:00:00.000-07:00"),  
    "summary" => "my_summary",
    "description" => "my_description"
);
```

Secondly, I figured Google Calendar API expected the data to be json, so in curl_setopt:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post_data));
```

This worked perfectly for me, hope it's useful to someone else as well!

Comment: For me is not working.
i tryed that code, or i'm doing wrong key, but i don't think so. is the one under : "Key for server apps (with IP locking) " i allowed all IP for now. authorization required even for me. Can i have access to your complete example please?